# How do we calculate output voltage in clipper circuits?

Tags: voltage, diodes, ac, rectifier, voltage-clipping

In the below circuit, when the diode is forward biased, the current is passing through it and not from load resistor (R_L), but the voltage across both of them (diode and R_L) is same as they are in parallel combination.

How come the voltage is fluctuating for "R_L" in the right graph? Considering R_L as output voltage (in the *right* graph), I think it should be the same as the *left* graph as the voltage across both the diode and R_L is same, as they are connected in parallel.

Below, the left graph is of the input voltage and the right graph is of the output voltage measured across R_L:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The current fluctuates too, and thus the voltage dropped across R1.

If you eliminate \$R_L\$ for simplicity, the voltage at A (wrt ground) will be the same as the Vin for Vin <= 0.7V. As the voltage Vin increases past 0.7V the diode starts to conduct and the voltage at point A stays at 0.7V until the input voltage drops below 0.7V. It is assumed that the diode (being more-or-less ideal) will conduct *unlimited* current to keep the forward voltage from increasing past 0.7V. If you shorted R1, and the input voltage was as shown the diode would be destroyed on the first positive half-cycle.

Putting \$R_L\$ back in, you can think of the voltage source, R1 and \$R_L\$ being equivalent to Vin' = \$\text {Vin} \cdot R_L/(R_L + R1) \$ with a source resistance of \$1/(1/R1+ 1/\text R_L\$ )- which is the Thevenin equivalent.

That's just a voltage divider, until you add the diode.

You can then see that it clips at 0.7V whenever  \$\text V_{\text {in}}\ge  0.7V \cdot (R1 + R_L)/R_L\$, and the output is equal to \$\text {Vin} \cdot R_L/(R_L + R1) \$ otherwise.

Comment: What I'm asking is that how come voltage is fluctuating across \$R_L\$ while it's connected in parallel with Diode? (Also, how much current should go between two branches (Here, at point A) should be determined by resistance, right? We can't calculate voltage according to current or by current)

Comment: The diode only limits the voltage across it (by passing current). It can’t supply voltage. So if the voltage would be less than 0.7V without the diode, the diode does nothing. And the voltage can be anything. In this case, a fraction of the input voltage.

Comment: The current i is just input voltage minus output voltage, all divided by R1. There are two cases- diode not conducting (just a voltage divider) and diode conducting (i = (Vin-0.7)/R1. You have to calculate them separately and determine which one is valid at any given time. The equations in my answer do that.

Comment: Got it! Many many thanks to you sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Looking for the idea

Perhaps we should first see what the meaning of all this is and only then determine the exact values ​​of the quantities…

The idea of ​​such a device called a "limiter" or "half-wave rectifier" is to "cut off" (do not pass through the load) one of the two half-waves (in this case the positive one) of the input AC voltage.

## Implementation

This can be done in two ways - *by turning off a switch in series* or *by turning on a switch in parallel* during the positive half-wave (a diode can act as a switch).

### Series limiter

In this configuration (not shown here), the diode is connected in series to the input voltage source and the load. So when the diode is *on*, the full voltage of the "ideal" input voltage source with zero internal resistance is applied to the load (excellent); when the diode is *off*, there is no any voltage applied (excellent).

### Parallel limiter

In this (OP's) configuration, the diode is connected in parallel to the load. But the input voltage source cannot be directly connected to this network because, when the diode is *on*, the source would be shorted by the diode acting as a "piece of wire". That is why, the  voltage source is connected through a resistor limiting the current (figuratively speaking, the  "ideal" voltage source is intentionally worsened and converted to a real voltage source with significant internal resistance).

So when the diode is *off*, an undesired voltage divider is formed by the resistor and the load... and only a part of the input voltage is applied through the resistor to the load (bad); when the diode is *on*, the load is shorted and there is no voltage applied (excellent).

### Series vs parallel

Like everything in this world, switches, including diodes, are not perfect - they have some high resistance when they are *off* and some small resistance when they are *on*.

From this point of view, the series configuration is better when the load is low resistance and vice versa, the parallel configuration is better when the load is high resistance.

Another advantage of the parallel configuration is that the switch is grounded while in the series circuit it is "floating"... but in the diode implementation this is not essential.

## Philosophy

We can think of the combination of the input voltage source and the resistor in series in OP's circuit as a *current source*. So we can derive two more rules for controlling electrical quantities...

- ***voltage is controlled by connecting a switch in series***
- ***current is controlled (diverted) by connecting a switch in parallel***

... and add them to our "collection of general circuit rules". I have made such a [collection of general circuit principles](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Circuit_Principles) in my [Circuit Idea](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea) wikibook.

See also [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/644152/61398) to a related question.